# Is it important to specify IssuerSigningKey?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

right now i have something like this

```
 options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
 {
      ValidateIssuer = auth.Issuer,
      ValidIssuer = auth.Issuer,
      ValidateAudience = auth.Audience
 };
 options.Authority = auth.Authority;
 options.Audience = auth.Audience;
```

i dont specify any IssuerSigningKey, will the key be generated automatically by azure or not? Also, will it use asymetric encryption or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't need to specify the `IssuerSigningKey` when we use azure ad to protect our web api. Because it is already be strict when we set up AAD in our project.

When we try to use azure ad to protect our API, we should send the Http request along with an access token inside the request header to try to visit the API. Since we are using Azure AD, we need to follow the usage of Azure AD.

In the API application, we need to have appsettings.json and codes in program.cs which means we need to check the access token with values below.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "azure_ad_ap_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenantid/common/organizations", // A guid (Tenant ID = Directory ID) or 'common' or 'organizations' or 'consumers'
  "Audience": "api://client_id"
},

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

When we generate access token, for example, using client credential flow.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id/common/organizations}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=azure_ad_ap_id
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret=client_secret
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

And let's see an example of the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-token-claims-reference#payload-claims).

[image]

We could see it's an jwt token and when we strict the tenant id, then the `iss` is also pointing to the tenant id. That means when we have code and setting like what I showed at first, it already asked us to provide a correct access token with correct iss.

what you have `TokenValidationParameters` is usually for the custom [jwt authentication](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/). I have a jwt auth sampl which needs to define auth scheme is program.cs like below. Like you see I set an `IssuerSigningKey`.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityService.Key);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThisismySecretKey")),
            //IssuerSigningKey = key,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
```

And my method for generating token.

```
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));//pointing to "ThisismySecretKey" 
 var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

 var claims = new[] {
     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "user_name"),
     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, "user_email"),
     new Claim("DateOfJoing", "2022-09-12"),
     new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
     new Claim("role","admin"),
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"admin")
 };

 var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
     _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
     claims,
     expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
     signingCredentials: credentials);

 return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```